# Create pyqtgraph plot without window opening and closing when moved to QGraphicsView

Tags: python, plot, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I am trying to create a line graph for a Pyqt application, the graph it self works fine but I am annoyed by the fact that it opens a window for a split second which then closes and the plot moves to the Qt QGraphicsView. I have searched for a solution but I can not seem to find any answers that work.

```
def lineChartTest(self):
    x = np.array(list(range(0, 10)))
    y = np.array([3, 7, 5, 11, 8, 13, 9, 16, 15, 12])
    x_smooth = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 300)
    spl = make_interp_spline(x, y, k=3)
    y_smooth = spl(x_smooth)

    plot = pg.plot()
    plot.setGeometry(0, 0, 1007, 500)
    plot.setLabel('bottom', 'X-axis Values')
    plot.setLabel('left', 'Y-axis Values')
    plot.setXRange(0, 10)
    plot.setYRange(0, 20)
    plot.setTitle("Test pyqtgraph")
    plot.setBackground('1E1B44')
    line = plot.plot(x_smooth, y_smooth, pen=pg.mkPen('E42AFF', width=2))
    plot.addLegend()

    self.scene.addWidget(plot)
```

This is the code I am using to create the plot currently.

Comment: Try to remove `plot.show()`.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work sadly.

Comment: @TroyB. please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plot()` function automatically *shows* the PlotWidget before returning it (see [sources](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pyqtgraph.html#plot)), so it's briefly displayed as a top level window before being added to the view.

Since you're not adding any arguments to `plot()`, you don't really need that function, and you can just create a new PlotWidget instance and add that to the view:

```
    def lineChartTest(self):
        # ...
        plot = pg.PlotWidget()
        # ...
```

On the other hand, a PlotWidget *already* is a QGraphicsView, so it might not have a lot of sense to add a view to the scene of another one. Consider using a PlotWidget instead of the QGraphicsView, and add PlotItems to it.

Comment: Thanks! This was great